# Automate the boring tasks - exercise - collatz function

Tags: python, loops

Beginner question here.

I have just attempted an exercise from Automate the boring stuff. I've completed the question in the format suggested by first defining a function as below:

"Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1."

and then using that same function, meeting those minimal constraints, to write a programme that meets the following requirements:

*Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.*

I've managed to generate a sequence of numbers ending with one, following the above rules, but my program prints each number in the sequence three times. Is anyone able to explain why this might be?

Thanks so much for your help

```
def collatz(number):
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
        print(int(number)//2)
        return int(number)//2
    else:
        print(3 * int(number) + 1)
        return 3 * int(number) + 1

collatz(5)    
print('Enter a number')

entry = input()

while collatz(entry) != 1:
    collatz(entry)
    entry = collatz(entry)
```

Comment: It prints it three times because you call the function in three separate locations.

Comment: You first call `collatz(5)`, then you call it on each `while` loop (`while collatz(entry)`), and then you call it two more times within the loop itself.

Comment: Couple things in terms of making your code look better, `1` you don't need to do `int(number)` on every instance, in fact, you can probably assume an `int` will be passed, and get rid of all of your `int()`. Also you can probably just get rid of the print statements and just use `return`

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should look like this:

```
entry = input()
while entry != 1:
    entry = collatz(entry)
```

Comment: Thanks Błotosmętek. I changed the loop as suggested and it now works. I am still slightly confused however. I would be very grateful if you could explain why if I run the program and enter 1 when prompted, the while loop still runs even though it's condition is false? Many thanks

Comment: I think I managed to figure it out... I guess the input is initially evaluated as a string? I changed the code as follows and it now works -  https://paste.ofcode.org/AF3kGHb28DxJAwY6LhSeE5 - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function 3 times and you have a `print` call in the function.

Only call the function once and I would remove the `print` statements from the `collatz` method and just `print` in the calling loop, e.g.:

```
In []:
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number//2
    return 3*number + 1

entry = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(entry)

while entry != 1:
    entry = collatz(entry)
    print(entry)

Out[]:
Enter a number: 10
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`def collatz(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 'Try again with an integer other than 0'
    elif number == 1:
        return 1
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        n = number // 2
        print(n)
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * number + 1
        print(n)
    while n != 1:
        n = collatz(n)
        return n
    return n`

The last statement `return n` in line 15 is optional.